# PseudoClass: notification from states broken on setting custom state

Tags: javafx, pseudo-class

Below is an example that doesn't behave like I expect it to behave - would like to find out if the behavior or  my expectation is wrong (can well be that I do something foolishly wrong ;).

What it does:

- it implements a custom button with a custom pseudo-class very much the same way as in the [code example in the java doc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html)
- it registers a listener on the observableSet returned by the button's `getPseudoClassStates()` that logs the active states on change
- it has ui (a simple button) that toggles the special state of the custom button

*Expected behavior*: notifications on interaction with the custom button via mouse/keyboard (hover, focused, armed ... )

*Actual behavior*: same as expected if the special state is not set, no notification after the special state has been set once

Questions:

- bug or feature?
- how to change the setup to be notified always?

The example:

```
public class PseudoStateNotification extends Application {
    private SpecialButton specialButton;
    private SetChangeListener sl;

    public static class SpecialButton extends Button {
        private static PseudoClass SPECIAL = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("special");
        private BooleanProperty special = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "special", false) {

            @Override
            protected void invalidated() {
                pseudoClassStateChanged(SPECIAL, get());
            }

        };

        public SpecialButton(String text) {
            super(text);
        }

        public void setSpecial(boolean sp) {
            special.set(sp);
        }

        public boolean isSpecial() {
            return special.get();
        }

        public BooleanProperty specialProperty() {
            return special;
        }
    }

    private Parent createContent() {
        sl = change -> LOG.info("pseudo-changed: " + change.getSet());
        specialButton =  new SpecialButton("custom buttom");
        specialButton.getPseudoClassStates().addListener(sl);
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(specialButton);
        Button toggle = new Button("toggle special state");
        toggle.setOnAction(e -> {
            specialButton.setSpecial(!specialButton.isSpecial());
        });
        pane.setBottom(toggle);
        return pane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent(), 200, 200));
        URL uri = getClass().getResource("pseudo.css");
        stage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(uri.toExternalForm());
        stage.setTitle(FXUtils.version());
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(PseudoStateNotification.class.getName());

}
```

The stylesheet pseudo.css:

```
.button:special {
  -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

---

Update:

As nicely tracked in [Jose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53582866/203657), the underlying reason is that `ObservaleSet<PseudoClass> Node.getPseudoClassStates()` returns a free-flying unmodifiable wrapper around the states which makes the returned set garbage-collectable. In my book [that's a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8214699) - comparable api as for instance `TableView.getVisibleLeafColumns()` is implemented correctly and keeps a strong reference to the wrapper. The hack-around is to keep a strong reference to the set in client code.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Which JavaFX version/OS are you using?

Comment: @fabian thanks for trying :) It's openjfx/jdk11 on win10 ... what's yours? Just to be on the safe side: you click the toggle button (to set the special state), then move the mouse over the custom and get notified about the changed set, that is now has the hover added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a matter of a custom state, but it is the usual case of weak listeners that are garbage collected at some point: your `SetChangeListener` will be gone after some time.

You can verify it by not clicking at all in the toggle button. Just hover a few times the button, and click on it. After some point you won't get any notification.

This is for instance a sequence of changes:

```
INFO: pseudo-changed: [focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, pressed, focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, pressed, focused, armed]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused, armed]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, pressed, focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, pressed, focused, armed]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused, armed]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, pressed, focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, pressed, focused, armed]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused, armed]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused]
```

After the last one I don't get notifications anymore.

To avoid this all we need to do is hold a strong reference of the observable set of pseudo classes:

```
private ObservableSet<PseudoClass> states;

private Parent createContent() {
    sl = change -> LOG.info("pseudo-changed: " + change.getSet());
    specialButton =  new SpecialButton("custom buttom");
    states = specialButton.getPseudoClassStates();
    states.addListener(sl);
    ...
}
```

Now it will work with any state change, both from the button or from the toggle button.

```
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: []
INFO: pseudo-changed: [special]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, special]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, pressed, special]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, pressed, focused, special]
...
INFO: pseudo-changed: [focused, special]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [special]
INFO: pseudo-changed: []
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover]
...
```

**EDIT**

While `finalize` has been deprecated, it still can be used to check that the listener is gc'ed in the first scenario:

```
specialButton.getPseudoClassStates().addListener(new SetChangeListener<PseudoClass>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends PseudoClass> change) {
            LOG.info("pseudo-changed: " + change.getSet());
        }

        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            super.finalize();
            LOG.info("SetChangeListener finalized by gc");
        }
    });
```

So in the above test, you will get:

```
...
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [focused]
INFO: pseudo-changed: [hover, focused]
INFO: SetChangeListener finalized by gc
```

and no more notifications after that, as mentioned before.

However, if you hold the strong reference, even if you call explicitly `System.gc()`, the listener won't be gc'ed.

It is also worth checking the `FXCollection::UnmodifiableObservableSet` implementation, where a `WeakSetChangeListener` is [used](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/a42b5841674ab7cd2704e0ea5fbcc94934d91c83/modules/javafx.base/src/main/java/javafx/collections/FXCollections.java#L1674), while holding a reference to the listener itself:

```
private SetChangeListener<E> listener;
private void initListener() {
        if (listener == null) {
            listener = c -> {
                callObservers(new SetAdapterChange<E>(UnmodifiableObservableSet.this, c));
            };
            this.backingSet.addListener(new WeakSetChangeListener<E>(listener));
        }
    }
```

This means that the reference `private SetChangeListener<E> listener;` is not really needed.

Comment: hmm .. was one of my ideas as well, but both listener and custom button have a strong reference in the app class, shouldn't that be enough to hold it active?

Comment: It looks like it is not. As the test proves, just changing states in the button makes the listener go away at some point. Having a reference to the button, pane or scene is not enough (I tested that as well), you need a reference to the observable set.

Comment: okay will test again, thanks :) but any idea why? That would mean a singularity in the whole of fx (listChangeListeners aren't garbage collected in such a context), so I would consider that behavior a bug in the BitSet implementation ..

Comment: arrgg .. we get a different instance of the set lof pseudoStates on each call: node does keep a reference on the - modifiable - original and wraps unmodifiableSet around it that's created on the fly ... totally unexpected for me. And totally different from the implementation of other unmodifiable (lists at least) wrapper api - TableView f.i. exposes a list of unmodifiable visibleLeafColumns, which is strongly referenced by the table. Really good dig by you :))

Comment: I've edited my question, with a usual hack that can be used to verify that it is gc effectively the one doing the job, and also including the reference to the implementation of the `UnmodifiableObservableSet`.